# Wordpress shows breakline instead of br after transfer

Tags: php, wordpress

I have transferred a website from 1 server to another. Everything went well except that it now shows \r\n everywhere on the site instead of changing into `<br/>`.

The version of PHP so that should work the same. What could be the problem? Have searched in the web but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I haven't experienced such a problem I can give you some clues. It appears to me as if the symbols have been replaced with http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php. 
My solution will be to edit all the applicable files with Find All and replace all the     `\r\n` parts with     `<br/>`. Of course, have a spare copy of the file just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but the solution was to not export the database via PhpMyAdmin. Instead I exported the database through the DirectAdmin panel of the hosting provider and imported that one and the problem was gone.

Hope this helps people dealing with this problem!